# Why is my python script not running in shared hosting cpanel GoDaddy

Tags: python, web, cpanel, web-hosting

I have shared hosting for my website at Godaddy with shared hosting in cpanel.  I made a python script that print hello and I even tried with the GUI too but it is not printing. It is only showing the code.  I called GoDaddy and they said to do `print("Hello World")` but even though I did it is still not working.  Right now my code is `print("Hello World")`.  Printing hello world like that normally works but it is not working.  I need to use python 2.6.6 because that's what GoDaddy gives as the version number for python.  Please can somebody help?

You can check out my python script in my website at [My python script in my website](https://flipperlab.com/test.py).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include all relevant information _here_, as part of your question. We're not going to go off-site just to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Now I don't get that error.  It shows me the code now.  You can see the code I put in the question.  Can you please tell me what else you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that python is installed on it but it doesn't let you run python scripts in godaddy economy hosting cpanel.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You use Apache Web server, and it doesn't process you python script. It consider it as static file and return it's content.

There are a few ways to make it work

- [mod_python](http://modpython.org/) for your Apache server
- Use [CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html)
- Make apach proxy to python web server by your choice (e.g. [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/))

Comment: Now it gives me a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Even in the other pages that are not python files